# check if object contains value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of nested objects that I get from database.

Each object has a member called "metadataIdStrings" which is a dictionary.

Example:

```
    [{
  "customerId": 48,
  "uploaderId": "markdolenc",
  "filename": "1.pdf",
  "createdOn": {
    "$date": "2020-08-25T12:06:10.165Z"
  },
  "lastModified": {
    "$date": "2020-08-28T06:16:40.352Z"
  },
  "deleted": false,
  "approved": true,
  "classification": 926,
  "nextUserId": 0,
  "nextRoleId": 0,
  "nextFlowItemId": null,
  "documentTypeId": 189,
  "metadataIdStrings": {
    "3968": "A1 Slovenija, d. d.",
    "3969": "A1 Slovenija, d. d.",
    "3970": "SI60595256",
    "3971": "1196332000",
    "3972": "Šmartinska cesta 134B",
    "3973": "Ljubljana",
    "3974": "1000",
    "3975": "",
    "3976": "",
    "3977": "SI56029220050478116",
    "3978": "LJBASI2X",
    "3979": "NOVA LJUBLJANSKA BANKA D.D.",
    "3980": "",
    "3981": "LJBASI2X",
    "3982": "Kibuba d.o.o.",
    "3983": "Kibuba d.o.o.",
    "3984": "SI16483324",
    "3985": "2036274000",
    "3986": "Selo pri Vodicah 11C",
    "3987": "Vodice",
    "3988": "1217",
    "3989": "",
    "3990": "",
    "3991": "SI56020370258031447",
    "3992": "LJBASI2X",
    "3993": "NOVA LJUBLJANSKA BANKA D.D.",
    "3994": "",
    "3995": "",
    "3996": "Račun",
    "3997": "20290063150",
    "3998": "",
    "3999": "SISI12901500469116",
    "4000": "EUR",
    "4001": "29.00",
    "4002": "",
    "4003": "6.38",
    "4004": "0.00",
    "4005": "35.38",
    "4006": "2020-05-05",
    "4007": "EUR",
    "4008": "",
    "4009": "",
    "4010": "",
    "4011": "",
    "4012": "",
    "4013": "",
    "4014": "",
    "4015": "",
    "4016": "",
    "4017": "",
    "4018": "",
    "4019": "",
    "4020": ""
  }
}]
```

I need to filter objects that contain a value inside "metadataIdStrings" based on search field.

The problem I'm facing is that the keys in that dictionary are not the same for all objects.

I was guessing I could do something like

```
filteredList(){
        var searchValue = this.search;

        return this.correctDocuments.filter(doc => {
            return Object.values(doc.metadataIdStrings).some(val => {
                var includes = val.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
                return includes
            }) 
        })
    }
```

But this is not really working, what am I missing?

EDIT:
As Peter suggested I went further to debug `this.correctDocuments.filter` and noticed that it returns the right items. The problem was that I had data binding to `this.search` inside a table, where it was searching for filename.
Silly mistakes.

Comment: Both approach and code look viable so far. What is the actual search value for the case that you think is failing? The audience also does not know anything about `this.correctDocuments` which is going to be filtered by the result of `Object.values(doc.metadataIdStrings).some( ... )`.

Comment: Actually everything. If I try to search for something like "love" or "Sloven" i get 0 results back.

Comment: Maybe you try debugging your code first yourself since e.g. `"A1 Slovenija, d. d.".toLowerCase().includes('slove'.toLowerCase())` returns the expected result. The next step was to test the outer structure ... 2min later ... checked ... `Object.values(doc.metadataIdStrings).some(val => {
    const includes = val.toLowerCase().includes('Slove'.toLowerCase());
    return includes
});` return `true` as expected. How about `this.correctDocuments.filter` then, which I was already referring to in first place?

Comment: @PeterSeliger I double checked, and you're right, return is as expected, so i will try to further debug the this.correctDocuments.filter

Comment: I edited the original question, and managed to solve the problem.

Comment: you've got my upvote; and next time you might prepare an example that gives a whole picture  to the problem. By doing so, you most probably will discover almost all of the bugs yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do these.

```
// Grab the metadataIdStrings
const { metadataIdStrings } = response

// Convert metadataIdStrings object as an array
Object.values(metadataIdStrings).filter(value => { /* add your filter logic here */ })

// If you need the keys
Object.keys(metadataIdStrings).filter(key => { /* metadataIdStrings[key] === something */ })
```

Also, it seems the array where you get metadataIdStrings from is an array with a single object. SO you should reference it properly.

Comment: I only pasted an array with single object (there can be n of them) as an example. All have the same structure, only the content inside "metadataIdStrings" differs (keys are not the same for all objects in the array).

Comment: have you tried using regular expressions instead of string.includes? It would be better if you can share some error message, or efforts to debug your code that fails so we can see whats going wrong.

Comment: There's no error message, i just get no results back, even though there are 3 "documents" that contain that string inside metadataIdStrings

Answer (score -1):

Let's first see something simple, yet close to your example working:

```
var items = [{
    "3968": "A1 Slovenija, d. d.",
    "3969": "A1 Slovenija, d. d.",
    "3970": "SI60595256",
    "3971": "1196332000",
    "3972": "Šmartinska cesta 134B",
    "3973": "Ljubljana",
    "3974": "1000",
    "3975": "",
    "3976": "",
    "3977": "SI56029220050478116",
    "3978": "LJBASI2X",
    "3979": "NOVA LJUBLJANSKA BANKA D.D.",
    "3980": "",
    "3981": "LJBASI2X",
    "3982": "Kibuba d.o.o.",
    "3983": "Kibuba d.o.o.",
    "3984": "SI16483324",
    "3985": "2036274000",
    "3986": "Selo pri Vodicah 11C",
    "3987": "Vodice",
    "3988": "1217",
    "3989": "",
    "3990": "",
    "3991": "SI56020370258031447",
    "3992": "LJBASI2X",
    "3993": "NOVA LJUBLJANSKA BANKA D.D.",
    "3994": "",
    "3995": "",
    "3996": "Račun",
    "3997": "20290063150",
    "3998": "",
    "3999": "SISI12901500469116",
    "4000": "EUR",
    "4001": "29.00",
    "4002": "",
    "4003": "6.38",
    "4004": "0.00",
    "4005": "35.38",
    "4006": "2020-05-05",
    "4007": "EUR",
    "4008": "",
    "4009": "",
    "4010": "",
    "4011": "",
    "4012": "",
    "4013": "",
    "4014": "",
    "4015": "",
    "4016": "",
    "4017": "",
    "4018": "",
    "4019": "",
    "4020": ""
  },
  {
    "continent": "EUR"
  },
  {something: "else"}];
```

I ignored `metadataIdStrings`-related stuff for now. Running

```
items.filter((item) => Object.keys(item).filter((k) => (item[k] && item[k].indexOf("EUR") >= 0)).length)
```

will yield correct results.

Now, let's apply this to your case:

```
items.filter((item) => item.metadataIdStrings && Object.keys(item.metadataIdStrings).filter((k) => (item.metadataIdStrings[k] && item.metadataIdStrings[k].indexOf("EUR") >= 0)).length)
```

Comment: I would be glad to know the reason for the down-vote. If it's a deficiency in my answer, I would be happy to improve it. But without comment, it's difficult to tell.